# Connecting RGB LED strip to pc controller

Tags: led, controller, rgb

I just bought a computer case Sharkoon pure steel rgb. It comes with 4 rgb fans that connects to a controller according to the following image:

[image]

After connecting these 4 fans I still have 4 more empty outputs from the controller.

I have some rgb led strip of around 50cm left from previous setups and I was wondering if connecting this led strip that left to the controller will work.

The rgb led strip is standard 5050 with 4 pins however here is it only 3 so I was wondering if it will work/cause any problems to the controller.

Thank you!